# Error en la fusión del manifiesto

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

Necesito su ayuda con un problema en mi proyecto en Android estudio.
tengo este mensaje de error:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 22 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [com.android.support:wear:28.0.0-alpha3] C:\Users\Eliseo\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\wear-28.0.0-alpha3.aar\c8815dc1b8fcb9d223abccd382bee9c9\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 22
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 22,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.wear" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

y este es mi código build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eliseo.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:wear:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.3.0'
}
```

resaltandome  en rojo: 
    `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'`

Les agradecería si son específicos dado que soy nuevo en  Android y en este sitio web.

Comment: Segun lo que entiendo del mensaje de error alguna de tus dependencias no son soportados por el SDK 22, y te recomiendo elevarlo, para ello cambia `minSdkVersion 22` a `minSdkVersion 23`

Comment: Solo debes cambiar la versión mínima a la 23 amigo, o quitar la dependencia que estás utilizando y es de la 23 pero actualmente estás en la 22 Lo recomendable es cambiar tu minSdkVersion a la 23 ! Suerte !

Comment: Al cambiar  minSdkVersion 22 por minSdkVersion 23 me resulta en este mensaje de error:Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:percent:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
 is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Desgraciadamente actualmente ya no se tiene soporte para la versión API 22 y esto es un problema ya que muchos dispositivos no cuentan con actualización para Android 6.0**

Como comentas, en realidad la librería tiene definido como `minSdkVersion 23`, ya que **actualmente no existe soporte de [Wear](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/wear-ui-library) para la API 22** (Junio 2018) que es la que tiene definida como mínimo tu proyecto, por esta razón te sugiere usarlo.

> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 22 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared
>   in library

Puedes buscar una versión de [Wear](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/wear-ui-library) anterior a la `26.0.x` aunque no lo considero recomendable.

**Como solución te sugiero actualizar tu dispositivo, muy probablemente tiene actualización Android 6.0**